# Will the universe ever be so big that charges won't be close enough to affect each other?

Tags: electromagnetism

Since there's a finite amount of charge in existence due to conservation of charge and the force of charges on each other dies off by 1/r^2, will the universe ever expand to a point where charges can't affect each other? Will there eventually be a point where there are only isolated clumps of charge throughout the universe? Or is that the current state of the universe?

Comment: Note that gravitational force also decreases as $1/r^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the force of charges on each other dies off by 1/r^2

Is there any real number for which $\frac{1}{r^2} = 0$?

No, of course not, so there will never be a point at which in theory charges are unable to affect each other. However the relative velocity between two particles can put them in the escape velocity of their potential quite easily when they're far away.

Your question gets at a more fundamental issue regarding the expansion of the universe known as the [cosmological constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant). If the universe was expanding too fast, matter would not get the chance to clump together (which is not the same thing as "affecting" other matter). If it was expanding too slowly, we would experience a deadly "big crunch".